# aplicación para enviar e-mail visual basic.net

Tags: vb.net, email, gmail

Estoy realizando una aplicación en vb.net que entre otras cosas, requiere enviar correos electrónicos. Tengo el código que funcionaba hasta mayo del 2022 pero google ahora no permite el acceso a aplicaciones menos seguras y el programa da error cuando intento enviar correo.  Agradezco de antemano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Investiga sobre algo llamado "Contraseña para aplicaciones", solo tienes que configurar eso en tu cuenta de gmail, y donde estaba la clave del correo colocar la contraseña para aplicaciones que te suministra gmail

Comment: Hola Rodrigo. Sí, muchas gracias. Acá encontré un video que explica como hacerlo y me funcionó a la perfección.   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rlhtIz_Xl9g